# Scrape data from clinicalTrials.gov

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a small Python function to scrape data from [clinicalTrials.gov](http://clinicalTrials.gov). From each Study Record, I wish to scrape the conditions that the study is targeting. For example, for [this](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT00550550) study record I want the following:

```
conditions = ['Rhinoconjunctivitis', 'Rhinitis', 'Conjunctivitis'. 'Allergy']
```

However, in each study record, there are different numbers of conditions. I have written the following script which gets the data:

```
page = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT00550550')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
studyDesign = soup.find_all(headers='studyInfoColData')
condition = soup.find(attrs={'class':'data_table'}).find_all('span')
for each in condition:
    print(each.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

like so:

```
b'Condition or disease'
b'Intervention/treatment'
b'Phase'
b'Rhinoconjunctivitis'
b'Rhinitis'
b'Conjunctivitis'
b'Allergy'
b'Drug: Placebo'
b'Biological: SCH 697243'
b'Drug: Loratadine Syrup 1 mg/mL Rescue Treatment'
b'Drug: Loratadine 10 mg Rescue Treatment'
b'Drug: Olopatadine 0.1% Rescue Treatment'
b'Drug: Mometasone furoate 50 mcg Rescue Treatment'
b'Drug: Albuterol 108 mcg Rescue Treatment'
b'Drug: Fluticasone 44 mcg Rescue Treatment'
b'Drug: Prednisone 5 mg Rescue Treatment'
b'Phase 3'
```

How can I now only get the condition without the intervention/treatment info?

Comment: I am also interested in web scrapping clinical trials website. Is this project of yours an open-source project? I'm fairly new to web scrapping and I don't know where to start. Would you be willing to share your script. I just basically want to make my own search engine for trials with specific conditions etc.

Comment: @MertKarakas Hi. Unforntatley my stuff won't be open source for quite a long time. However, if your intrested check out [OpenTrials](https://opentrials.net/). Most of [their code](https://github.com/opentrials/) is open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the first `table` with class `data_table` & extract `span` element in `td` :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT00550550')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
studyDesign = soup.find("table", {"class" : "data_table"}).find('td')
conditions = [ t.text.strip() for t in studyDesign.find_all('span') ]
print(conditions)
```

which gives :

```
[u'Rhinoconjunctivitis', u'Rhinitis', u'Conjunctivitis', u'Allergy']
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02656888"
url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT00550550"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all("table", class_="data_table")

tds = [tr.find_all("td") for tr in table]
conditions = [condition for condition in (tds[0][0].get_text().split("\n")) if condition != ""]

print(conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to scrape clinicaltrials.gov is to create an account on https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/connect and use the credentials to connect to the AACT PostgreSQL database that stores this data.

Among everything else, you can find the data that you are looking for in the ctgov.conditions table.

```
select name from ctgov.conditions where nct_id = 'NCT00550550';
```